# React-table rowspan

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, react-table

I use react-table to display my data as follows in the image below,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otuBH.png)

and I find a diffucult to configure the props columns,
to have a presentation as in the picture,

my data :

```
const data = { cat :' favorite', 
              subCat : [ { id :1,
             discritpion : 'text'
             status : 'active' 
           },
           { id :2,
             discritpion : 'text 2'
             status : 'inactive' 
           }
          ],
         cat : 'least favorite', 
              subCat : [ { id :1,
             discritpion : 'text'
             status : 'active' 
           },
           { id :2,
             discritpion : 'text 2'
             status : 'inactive' 
           }
          ]
        }


const columns = [{
  Header: 'Category',
  accessor: 'cat'
},
{
  Header: 'description',
  accessor: 'subCat.description'
}, {
  Header: 'status',
  accessor: 'subCat.status'
}, {
  Header: 'id',
  accessor: 'subCat.id',
}
  ]

return (
    <ReactTable
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
/>
```

in advance thank you for your help